# JavaScript doesn't recognize my function when loading content async?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I want to have a "read more"-click function on a text. I'm dynamically loading a Wikipedia text for a specific keyword and have this function:

```
function setText(text, lang, full) {
    setTimeout(function () { $('#loading').fadeOut('fast'); }, 300);
    var mylang = '<?= $_SESSION['lang']; ?>';
    if (mylang != 'en' && lang == 'en')
        var AppendText = '<span class="db f09 grey mt10"><?= __('TEXT_ONLY_ENGLISH'); ?></span>';

    console.log(lang);

    if (full) {
        $('#text').html('<?= __('EMPTY'); ?>');
        setTimeout(function () { $('#text').fadeIn('fast'); }, 500);
    } else if (text) {
        // Full Text
        function fullText() {
            console.log('yes');
            setText(text, lang, 1);
        }

        text = text.length > length ? text.substring(0, length - 3) +
        '... <a class="cp" onclick="fullText()"><?= __('MORE') ?></a>' : text;
        $('#text').html(text).append(AppendText);
        setTimeout(function () { $('#text').fadeIn('fast'); }, 500);
    }
};
```

As you can see in the `else if` part I defined the `fullText()` function set to onclick on the anchor tag. I always get the message `fullText is not defined` when I click on it.
I just want to re-call the same `setText()` function with the variable `full` set to `1`, so the full text will be displayed instead of

> Sometext... (more)

Is this possible without using `ajax`? What options do I have?

PS: I also already tried calling `setText()` itself instead of `fullText()` but that won't be recognized as a defined function either.

Comment: Not related to your issue, but FYI, you don't need those `setTimeout` calls. You can use `.delay()` instead. `$('#text').delay(500).fadeIn('fast');`

Comment: Okay, good to know, thanks. @squint

Comment: The `fullText` function is scoped to the function where it's defined, and so an `onclick` attribute won't be able to see it, since it'll be looking for it in the global scope.

Comment: Where is `length` defined?

Comment: Even if I put it outside the setText function it won't be recognized if you suggested that? @squint

Comment: `length` is a Javascript function to count the letters of my text. @guest271314 (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp)

Comment: There is also `'` quotes inside of `'` at `var AppendText = '<span class="db f09 grey mt10"><?= __('TEXT_ONLY_ENGLISH'); ?></span>';`

Comment: `length` of what? What does `console.log(length)` log at `console`?

Comment: The trouble with putting `fullText` in the global scope is that it will no longer be able to see your `text` and `lang` variables. You should create the `<a>` element such that you can assign the handler directly to it. I don't use jQuery, so I'll let others show you how.

Comment: I would be also happy about a pure Javascript solution if you have it. So I could rewrite it to jQuery. @squint

Comment: I'm also unfamiliar with some of the`<?=` markup. As @guest271314 noted, it appears as though the single quotes are closed too early, but maybe that gets handled on the server?

Comment: That's PHP and doesn't affect the javascript code. I'm just dynamically loading text there depending on the users language. So I would get the same error if I remove that and just write plain text there.

Comment: One offtopic question again to squint: Why is `delay` "better" than `setTimeout`?

Comment: Not necessarily better. Just a little shorter and cleaner if you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `onclick` attribute you can only reference functions that are in the global scope. To get around this, you can attach an event handler dynamically instead of using the `onclick` attribute.

To get that done, I would suggest some changes, that lead to the following code:

```
function setText(text, lang, full) {
    setTimeout(function () { $('#loading').fadeOut('fast'); }, 300);
    var mylang = '<?= $_SESSION['lang']; ?>';
    // change 1: define an element with jQuery 
    var $appendText = $('<span>');
    if (mylang != 'en' && lang == 'en')
        $appendText.addClass('db f09 grey mt10').text('<?= __('TEXT_ONLY_ENGLISH')?>');

    console.log(lang);

    if (full) {
        // change 2: use text(), not html()
        $('#text').text('<?= __('EMPTY'); ?>');
    } else if (text) {
        // Full Text
        // Change 3: define link as jQuery element:
        var $link = $('<a>');
        if (text.length > length) {
            text = text.substring(0, length - 3);
            $link.addClass('cp').text('<?= __('MORE') ?>');
            // Change 4: attach click handler here:
            $link.click(function fullText() {
                console.log('yes');
                setText(text, lang, 1);
            });
        }
        // Change 5: append these jQuery elements, which can be empty:
        $('#text').text(text).append($link).append($appendText);
    }
    // Change 6: move this out of the if-block, as it is the same for both cases:
    setTimeout(function () { $('#text').fadeIn('fast'); }, 500);
};
```

Note that you did not provide the definition of the variable `length`, but I assume it is available to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Because         `function fullText()` is local to `setText` the click event executes on the global scope and does not know of `fullText()` 
Do not add your A element with inner html but do it by `createElement`

something like:

```
var hr = document.createElement("A");
hr.className="cp";
hr.onclick= function  {
            console.log('yes');
            setText(text, lang, 1);
        }
 $('#text').appendChild(hr)
```

will create a closure and solve the problem.

Comment: It won't be recognized either, if I put it outside of `setText()`.

Comment: @Vaia OK gave a solution as well

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** The other answers above are better because they take advantage of jQuery and make more sense; my partial solution (only the edits I made) is not dependent on jQuery.

Try something like this:

```
var fullText;
function setText(text, lang, full) {
    setTimeout(function () { $('#loading').fadeOut('fast'); }, 300);
    var mylang = '<?= $_SESSION['lang']; ?>';
    if (mylang != 'en' && lang == 'en')
        var AppendText = '<span class="db f09 grey mt10"><?= __('TEXT_ONLY_ENGLISH'); ?></span>';

    console.log(lang);

    if (full) {
        $('#text').html('<?= __('EMPTY'); ?>');
        setTimeout(function () { $('#text').fadeIn('fast'); }, 500);
    } else if (text) {
        // Full Text
        fullText = function() {
            console.log('yes');
            setText(text, lang, 1);
        }

        text = text.length > length ? text.substring(0, length - 3) +
        '... <a class="cp" onclick="fullText()"><?= __('MORE') ?></a>' : text;
        $('#text').html(text).append(AppendText);
        setTimeout(function () { $('#text').fadeIn('fast'); }, 500);
    }
};
```

O_Z is correct in his answer, in that `function fullText` is only defined inside an instance of `setText()`. Calling this function from anywhere inside `function setText` would normally work the way you would expect, however you are calling `fullText()` from a **global** `onclick` handler, by writing the HTML code, and therefore has no clue as to the specific instance of `setText()` that defined the relevant `function fullText`.

This solution has one major problem, however, which is that if `setText()` is called multiple times before the relevant documents are loaded, `fullText()` would only reference the most recent document, not both. To solve this, I would actually make a global array to store different `fullText` functions into, and write into the HTML which index in that array to run, and then removing the stored function from the array if it is not necessary anymore (to avoid a memory leak). There is another example below:

```
var fullTextFunctions = [];
function setText(text, lang, full) {
    setTimeout(function () { $('#loading').fadeOut('fast'); }, 300);
    var mylang = '<?= $_SESSION['lang']; ?>';
    if (mylang != 'en' && lang == 'en')
        var AppendText = '<span class="db f09 grey mt10"><?= __('TEXT_ONLY_ENGLISH'); ?></span>';

    console.log(lang);

    if (full) {
        $('#text').html('<?= __('EMPTY'); ?>');
        setTimeout(function () { $('#text').fadeIn('fast'); }, 500);
    } else if (text) {
        // Full Text
        fullTextFunctions.push(function fullText() {
            console.log('yes');
            setText(text, lang, 1);
        })

        text = text.length > length ? text.substring(0, length - 3) +
        '... <a class="cp" onclick="fullTextFunctions[' + (fullTextFunctions.length - 1) + ']()"><?= __('MORE') ?></a>' : text;
        $('#text').html(text).append(AppendText);
        setTimeout(function () { $('#text').fadeIn('fast'); }, 500);
    }
};

function releaseFullTextFunction(index) {
    fullTextFunctions[index] = null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, I really appreciate it and learned a lot! It's good to know how JS works in the background. So as far as I understood it, you mean that if `text` would change I should prefer creating this solution with an array?

Comment: More that if the function `setText` is called multiple times before `fullText` is called, the variable/function `fullText` only references the most recent time `setText` was called. So if you want different instances of `setText` to reference different instances of `fullText`, you must store the instance in a global array/object with a unique identifier, assuming you were to stick with calling `fullText` from the HTML `onclick` handler.